# Cannot debug service even if it is registered in the container

Tags: php, symfony

I use the following to learn about services and their definition:

```
<?php
namespace Members\Bundle\ManagementBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function learnAction()
    {
        $container= new ContainerBuilder();
        $container->register('test_service','User');
        var_dump($container->hasDefinition('test_service')); // return true
        return new Response("hi");
    }

}
```

The service `test_service` is registered and the `var_dump` echoes `true`. But when I come back to console and try to debug using:

```
php app/console container:debug test_service
```

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
>   The service definition "test_service" does not exist.
>
> container:debug [--show-private] [--tag="..."] [--tags]
>   [--parameter="..."] [--p arameters] [name]

What am I not understanding well? Your usual help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your services in one of the configuration files loaded by Symfony when building your container.

In your example you're manually instantiating a container builder, but this is not the builder used by Symfony when defining its container.

If you define your service in for example app/config/services.yml it will be available for the console command.

Comment: Aah now I understand . +1. Thank you very much Sir. One question please, is it possible to use the same container builder used by Symfony without config files? (In case we want to avoid Config Component). Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do so in container extensions or compiler passes. Have a look at the documentation of the [Dependency Injection Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html).

Comment: Ooh  these are exactly the new notions I am planning to read. Thanks a lot.